# Disable page transitions in Ionic 2 RC.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

How to disable transitions for all pages in ionic 2 ?

ionic 2 [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#nav-controller) allows you to do it on a specific view like so

```
nextPage() {
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {}, {animate: false})
}
```

but how can I disable all transitions for all pages globally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To disable animation for all your navigation go to your app.module.ts file and add to the config animate:false

Like so:

```
    IonicModule.forRoot(App, { animate: false })
```

Comment: Why isn't that option documented on the site: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/ ?

There are a lot of options there, but 'animate' is not listed. What other options may be used?

Comment: Just animate, I didn't see at the time any other options (2 years ago). I found this by literally looking through the source code for an hour.

Comment: Bad choice, this also disables animations for toasts